# Specflow + MSTest: tests fails with error "Could not load file or assembly 'MyPlugin.SpecFlowPlugin' or one of its dependencies"

Tags: c#, .net, mstest, specflow

I am running specflow tests using MSTest and command line. 
Project builds without errors but tests fails with an error:

```
    Class Initialization method MyProject.SpecFiles.MyFeature.FeatureSetup threw exception. TechTalk.SpecFlow.SpecFlowException: TechTalk.SpecFlow.SpecFlowException: Unable to load plugin: MyPlugin. Please check http://go.specflow.org/doc-plugins for details. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyPlugin.SpecFlowPlugin' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
.
+++++++++++++++++++
STACK TRACE:
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.RuntimePluginLoader.LoadPlugin(PluginDescriptor pluginDescriptor)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.RuntimePluginLoader.LoadPlugin(PluginDescriptor pluginDescriptor)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestRunContainerBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass3.<LoadPlugins>b__1(PluginDescriptor pd)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ConcatIterator>d__71`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestRunContainerBuilder.LoadPlugins(IRuntimeConfigurationProvider configurationProvider, ObjectContainer container)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestRunContainerBuilder.CreateContainer(IRuntimeConfigurationProvider configurationProvider)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunnerManager.CreateTestRunner(TestRunnerKey key)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunnerManager.GetTestRunner(TestRunnerKey key)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunnerManager.GetTestRunner(Assembly testAssembly, Boolean async)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunnerManager.GetTestRunner()
   at MyProject.SpecFiles.MyFeature.FeatureSetup(TestContext testContext) in d:\Jenkins\workspace\MyProject\SpecFiles\MyFeature.feature.cs:line 0
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resolved. I've added .testsettings file with checked Deployment checkbox. Items for Deployment - bin folder with all necessary dlls.

Answer (score 0):

The problem will probably be that your plugin dll (or one of its dependencies) is not found in the place that specflow is expecting to load it from.

you can specify a location to find the plugin in the app .config as [explained in the documentation](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Plugins):

> The following example is used to load a plugin assembly called "MyNewPlugin.SpecFlowPlugin.dll" that is located in a folder called "Binaries" that is at the same level of the current project.

```
<specFlow>
    <plugins>
        <add name="MyNewPlugin" path="..\Binaries" />
    </plugins>
</specFlow>
```

Check the output on the build server to see where the plugin dll is being created, and either adjust the build or the config appropriately

Comment: The following rows exists in App.config                                         '<plugins>
      <add name="MyPlugin" path="." type="Runtime" />
    </plugins>'     When I run tests using Visual Studio this problem does not exist, but if I use command line and MStest.exe this problem occurs

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you trying to load assembly in your project. In order to load assembly you have to add this following code in your app.config.

```
<stepAssemblies>
     <stepAssembly assembly="{name-of-assembly-containing-bindgins}" /> 
</stepAssemblies>
```

Comment: There are stepAssemblies in App.config.